# Javascript faceted search

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this page I'm working on, I'm trying to make a facted search for it. (only issue is I have no json as I'm looping through via `django`.)

What I currently have is this:

```js
var wood = []
$(".checkbar").click(function() {
  id = this.id
  $('.spe_' + id).toggleClass("filteredlabel");

  $('.flr').addClass("hide");
  $('.flr_spe_' + id).removeClass("flr hide").addClass("flrcheck");
  if (this.classList[1] == 'checked') {
    if (wood.length > 0) {
      debugger;
      $('.flr_spe_' + this.id).removeClass("hide").addClass("flr");
      for (var i = 0; i < wood.length; i++)
        if (wood[i] === this.id) {
          if (wood.length > 1) {
            $('.flr_spe_' + this.id).addClass("hide");
          }
          if (wood.length == 1) {
            $('.flr').removeClass("hide");
          }
          wood.splice(i, 1);
          break;
        }
    }
    $(this).toggleClass("checked");
  } else {
    $(this).toggleClass("checked");
    wood.push(this.id)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="checkbar" id="1">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="tick"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></div>

    Oak (1)
  </div>
</div>

<div class="checkbar" id="2">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="tick"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></div>

    Pine (1)
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 flr flr_spe_1 flr_rg_1">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body" align="center">
      <div class="flrimagecontainer">
        <img class="flrimg" src="/media/images/wood/st_tobacco2x.png" alt="Logo" />
        <div class="flrafter">
          <p class="spectitle">SPECIES</p>
          <p class="spec">Oak</p>
          <p class="spectitle">RANGE</p>
          <p class="spec">Old Wood</p>
          <p class="spectitle">STYLE</p>
          <p class="spec">Herringbone</p>
          <p class="spectitle">TEXTURE</p>
          <p class="spec">Prme</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="col-md-4 flr flr_spe_2 flr_rg_1">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body" align="center">
      <div class="flrimagecontainer">
        <img class="flrimg" src="/media/images/wood/straightwood_CfuTJb4.png" alt="Logo" />
        <div class="flrafter">
          <p class="spectitle">SPECIES</p>
          <p class="spec">Pine</p>
          <p class="spectitle">RANGE</p>
          <p class="spec">Old Wood</p>
          <p class="spectitle">STYLE</p>
          <p class="spec">Herringbone</p>
          <p class="spectitle">TEXTURE</p>
          <p class="spec">Prme</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is when I have to start adding more checkboxes to filter on. If i add another set of checkboxes for range, how would I go about making this so that they filter correctly together?

e.g. if I check Old Wood, And then Check Pine, How can I get just the results that have "Old Wood" and "Pine" and not return Oak?

Many Thanks

Comment: Can you insert some data?

Comment: @Saeed.At I have? the only thing missing is styles?

Comment: Checkboxes!! Attributes of items which are related to checkboxes. I can not understand these, from youe question

Comment: @Saeed.At There are no checkboxes, The Div checkbar exists already as a click element?

Comment: I can't understand what you do in your `js` codes, but you should create a copy of woods, loop over this copy, and if there is no attribute which is checked for an item, remove that from copy array, and show that array again in html.